# How can I replace a halogen light bulb inside this glass enclosure?

Tags: light, bulb

I have to replace this fused lightbulb but it is being caged by the glass as seen in the photo. How do I remove the glass?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On the ones I have that are similar lifting on the metal tab at the end with a little force it pulls off. Then the lamp is pulled to the side and taken out. To re assemble put the new lamp in without touching the lamp use a tissue or the packaging material any finger oils on the lamp may cause it to get hot and explode when it is turned on. I usually will clean the protective cover and snap it back in place. Sometimes this cover can be very stiff but they are easier to snap back in place.

Comment: Is the metal tab part of a band that clamps around the metal at the end of the assembly?